SingleChildScrollView obscured by keyboard
I have a strange behavior in my flutter code, this is the code:
class MyWidget extends ConsumerWidget {

Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    ...
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: WidgetAppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: PageContainer(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: AutofillGroup(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [ 
                ....

The problem is that when the keyboard appears, it obscures the bottom fields. That was working before I upgrade to the latest version of Flutter.
Any idea how to debug this ?

Have you tried to give  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true to Scaffold?

weird, never met in my life

@DroidFlutter same, not working

It might be due to changes in the default behavior of the keyboard handling mechanism. Try some other solutions... wrap SingleChildScrollView with ListView or manual handling with WidgetsBindingObserver

i think this code actually work.İdk whats wrong but pls try "primary : true" of SingleChildScrollView

same, not working !

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
